# Нужна ли запятая на стыке союзов "но... чем"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Но, чем больше ты учишься, тем сильнее становишься. Нужна ли запятая на стыке "Но...чем"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Но чем*** больше ты учишься, **тем** сильнее становишься.

Союз ***ЧЕМ...ЧЕМ*** является составным (как и союзы ЕСЛИ...ТО, ХОТЯ...НО), поэтому **запятая на стыке  сочинительного союза (в данно случае присоединительного союза *НО*) и первой частью двойного союза *ЧЕМ* не ставится.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140

*Звуки постепенно замирали, и чем дальше уходили мы от дома, тем глуше и мертвее становилось вокруг (М. Г.)*

Пример:

***Но чем*** ближе было время сна, **тем** беспокойнее Колюня становился, плохо ужинал, упрямился и не хотел идти спать. [Алексей Варламов. Купавна // «Новый Мир», 2000]

Comment: как же понятно вы всё объяснили...